# Sybil attack in Fanet using OMNET++

Tags: security, omnet++

so i am working on a project "detecting compromised nodes in flying ad-hoc network", for this purpose i am trying to implement a malicious node which perform a Sybil attack , so is there any idea about how to implement this attack ! thank you